# Facebook Direct Url to Post a message on someone's wall

Tags: android, html, ios, facebook, url

I'm developing an iOS application that must post on someone's Facebook wall message.
I found url scheme when the user have installed Facebook app. (url is like fb://publish/profile/{fbid}?text={message}
I want to find a direct url to post on someone's wall in browser.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, you should use the Dialog API to post a status message to someone feed (https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=123050457758183&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fresponse&display=touch).

Dialog API doc: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/

Comment: That link seems to point to something else now.  Is there still dialog documentation on FB?